# Material UI - how to remove padding from Container when width becomes xs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want the Container to have no padding when Container becomes xs.

I tried the following: https://material-ui.com/api/container/, but I can't get it working. If I add root instead of maxWidthXs in StyledContainer then padding becomes 0 for all sizes, but I only want padding to be 0 if Container size is xs.

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
const StyledContainer = withStyles({
    maxWidthXs: {
        paddingRight: "0",
        paddingLeft: "0",
        paddingTop: "0",
        paddingBottom: "0",
    },
    root: {},
})(Container);

export default function SimplePaper(props) {
    // const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <StyledContainer maxWidth="xl" xs={12}>
            <Paper
                style={{
                    alignItems: "center",
                    display: "flex",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    padding: "10px",
                }}
                elevation={10}
            >
                {props.children}
            </Paper>
        </StyledContainer>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 9):

MUI containers have `disableGutters`, which does exactly what you need without the need of restyling the entire component. You could go, for example, with something like:

```
<Container disableGutters={props.breakpoint === 'xs'}>
```

More info here: https://mui.com/api/container/#props

Answer (score 2):

This helped me MUI v5:

```
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import useMediaQuery from '@mui/material/useMediaQuery';
```

...

```
 const theme = useTheme();
```

..

```
<Container disableGutters={useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.only('xs'))}>
```

https://mui.com/components/use-media-query/#using-muis-breakpoint-helpers
https://mui.com/customization/breakpoints/#theme-breakpoints-only-key-media-query

Answer (score 0):

[Breakpoints](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/) would be one way to do it:

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";

const StyledContainer = withStyles((props) => {
    return ({
        root: {
            paddingRight: "10px",
            paddingLeft: "10px",
            backgroundColor: "green",
            [props.breakpoints.only('xs')]: {
                paddingRight: "0",
                paddingLeft: "0",
            },
        },
    })
})(Container);

export default function SimplePaper(props) {
    // const { classes } = props;

    return (
        <StyledContainer maxWidth="xl" xs={12}>
            <Paper
                style={{
                    alignItems: "center",
                    display: "flex",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    padding: "10px",
                }}
                elevation={10}
            >
                {props.children}
            </Paper>
        </StyledContainer>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using MUI v5 and applying `disableGutters` to my `Container` components was not removing the padding.

In my case, it was due to container style overrides taking priority over other props that modify styles.
To resolve it, I had to account for a case when `disableGutters` is passed as a prop and I did it as follows:

```
// theme.ts

const theme = createTheme({
...
components: {
  MuiContainer: {
    styleOverrides: {
       root: (ownerState) => ({
          // Set custom padding if disableGutters was not added as a prop
          padding: (!ownerState.disableGutters && '2px') || undefined
        })
      }
    }
  }
  ...
})
```

Now in your case, you can go to your Container component and do:

```
// [YourComponent].tsx
...
const matchesXs = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.only('xs'));

<Container disableGutters={matchesXs} />
```

You might also want to check out this related issue: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/30825